# undefined error while accessing an object from .ts file to .html in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to access an object value sent via a .ts file on .html file but it shows

```
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: co.productdetail is undefined
View."
```

here the productdetail is the variable name that i am trying to pass from the .ts file to the .html file.This is the way I am trying to print the name attribute of object in the html file `<h3>{{productdetail.name}}</h3>`.
however following seems to work fine in another file.

```
<div class="width50" *ngFor="let object of dataList">
<img src="{{object.images[0].src}}" width="150"  (click)="navigateToPage(object.id)" />
```

here datalist is an array of objects passed from the .ts file to .html file.
Kindly suggest a solution to the same.

Comment: Stay tuned lots of issues to come I am new to ionic.

Comment: sure.. reach me at fb @ aravind2109

Comment: could you please give a look to my other questions too most of them do not seem to get much attention probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use typesafe **`?`** operator to avoid this error

```
<h3>{{productdetail?.name}}</h3>
```

Reason:

- DOM elements are rendered even before `ngOnInit()` is fired.
- If you are using data from the service response, the bindings will have them as undefined until the response is received.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes it, but is it even correct to be trying to display data this way or is this just a 'hotfix' for a problem before?