# Rerendering Datatable in Angular 2 - dtInstance.then error

Tags: angular, datatable

I have a component in my angular 2 application which has a dropdown list and a datatable. Based on the name selected from the dropdown list, I want to display the details in the datatable.

HTML -

```
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedName">
    <option *ngFor="let name of nameList" value= {{name.firstName}} >
      {{name.firstName}}
    </option>
  </select>

  <button id="submitName" (click)="getData()">Go</button>
</div>

<table #myTable [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" datatable class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="retrievedNames">


      <tr *ngFor="let name of retrievedNames">
        <td>{{name.id}}</td>
        <td>{{name.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{name.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{name.middleName}}</td>
      </tr>


  </tbody>

</table>
```

My component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { NetworkService } from './../services/network.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-namedetails',
  templateUrl: './namedetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./namedetails.component.css']
})
export class NameDetails implements OnInit {

@ViewChild("myTable") myTable:DataTableDirective;

  private nameList: any;
  private selectedName:string;

  private retrievedNames: any;
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  dtElement: DataTableDirective;

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};


  constructor(private _http:Http, private networkservice : NetworkService,private router: Router) { 
 }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.fetchFirstNames();

  }

  fetchFirstNames(){

    this.networkservice.getAllFirstNames()
          .subscribe(

            res => {
              console.log(res);
              this.nameList = res;
            });

  }

  fetchAllDetails(){

    this.networkservice.getAllNames(this.selectedName)
          .subscribe(

            res => {
              console.log(res);
              this.retrievedNames = res;
              this.myTable.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
                  // Destroy the table first
                  dtInstance.destroy();
                  // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
                  this.dtTrigger.next();
                });
            });

  }


  getData(){

      this.fetchAllDetails();
  }

}
```

However I keep getting the following error - "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reinitialize Datatable - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864875/reinitialize-datatable-angular-2)

Comment: update the previous question with the solution to the problem there ... this is kind of a follow up question !!!

Comment: updated already. what else is the issue you are facing

Comment: the "this.myTable.dtInstance.then" throws error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: did you try my solution.?

Comment: @aravind - your answer to the previous question ? yes i tried it but it didnt work ... i have posted my comment to your solution

Comment: no I am not ....

Comment: Ok. what is the actual problem. to solve `undefined` use **`?`** as in this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862258/undefined-error-while-accessing-an-object-from-ts-file-to-html-in-ionic-3/44864299#44864299) still you have issue update me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148151/discussion-between-shiv-baral-and-aravind).

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the following method to your `component.ts` class:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.dtTrigger.next();
}
```

Otherwise the initialisation of the instance is never triggered, so the dtInstance is never created in the first place; which is why it is null.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! How did you find this information?