# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in rerender function of datatable in angular 4

Tags: angular, datatables

I am implementing jquery datatable in angular 4. I am populating table by searching date range. so i need to destroy datatable before every search.

> But this function "rerender()" throwing this error: ERROR TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
  rerender():void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        // Destroy the table first
        dtInstance.destroy();
        // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    })
}
```

Full code:

```
 export class vendorTransactionComponent implements OnInit {

        @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
        dtElement: DataTableDirective;
        dtOptions: any = {};
        dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

        Vendors: any[];
        data: any[];
        fromDate: Date = new Date();
        toDate: Date = new Date();
        VendorId: number = 1;
        ClientId: number;
        items = new Array;
        itemCount = 0;
        searchkey: any;
        IsTableVisible: boolean = false;
        IsLoadingDivVisible: boolean = false;
        itemLimit = 10;
        vendortransactionList: any[] = [];
        constructor(private vendortrans_serv: vendorTransactionServices) {
            this.ClientId = ConstantData.ClientID;
            this.vendortrans_serv.GetAllVendor().subscribe(data => {
                this.Vendors = data;
            });

        }
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.dtOptions = {
                pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                //pageLength: 2,
                responsive: true,
            };

        }

        rerender():void {
            this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
                // Destroy the table first
                dtInstance.destroy();
                // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
                this.dtTrigger.next();
            })
        }

        GetVendortransaction() {
            this.vendortransactionList = [];
            this.IsTableVisible = false;
            this.IsLoadingDivVisible = true;
            this.rerender();
            this.vendortrans_serv.GetVendortransactions(this.fromDate.toDateString(), this.toDate.toDateString(), this.ClientId, this.VendorId)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        this.vendortransactionList = data;
                        this.IsTableVisible = true;
                        // this.dtTrigger.next();
                    }
                    this.IsLoadingDivVisible = false;
                });
        }
    }
```

i am following the below article
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender

Comment: Use `rerender(): void {` I am afraid `this` is pointing to something different when using `rerender() {`...It is not even af function.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867345/rerendering-datatable-in-angular-2-dtinstance-then-error/ I have answered it there.